# Creating a CSV for each element in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a List L where each item is a data frame. I now want to save each item in a separate csv. I tried the below code but it didn't pass.

```
for i in length(list) {
    write.csv(to.data.frame(list[i]), 'list_item_number_@{i}')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by putting your `for` loop sequence into parentheses, meaning that

`for i in length(list)` should be `for(i in 1:length(list))`.

Next, there's a problem with `to.data.frame(list[i])`, because you're operating over a list.  So this should be `to.data.frame(list[[i]])`

Third, what is `to.data.frame()`?  I think you mean `as.data.frame()` perhaps. Either way, you probably don't need it.

Also, I'm not quite sure what you're doing with `'list_item_number_@{i}'`, but you should create as many files as you have list elements and assign each one with `[i]` in the loop.  Something like this, if the list is length 3.

```
files <- c("f1.csv", "f2.csv", "f3.csv")
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    write.csv(list[[i]], file = files[i], row.names = FALSE)
}
```

You'll probably want `row.names = FALSE` also, to avoid a headache.

...**but a more *R* way to do this would be with** `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(list), function(i){
    write.csv(list[[i]], files[i], row.names = FALSE)
    })
```

which will return a list of `NULL`s, which can be suppressed by wrapping it with `invisible()`